# Azure Function Java BindingName for Blob Storage (event-based) is not working

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I followed the instructions from the below url and got this to work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-event-grid-blob-trigger?pivots=programming-language-java

However, I get a null pointer exception when I use @BindingName("name").

```
[2023-01-24T03:35:11.842Z] Executed 'Functions.BlobTriggerEventGrid' (Failed, Id=9945bf16-f234-4a76-8f4d-ba98ba7856f6, Duration=192ms)
[2023-01-24T03:35:12.013Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.BlobTriggerEventGrid. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: FailureException: NullPointerException:
Stack: java.lang.NullPointerException
[2023-01-24T03:35:12.076Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.BindingDataStore.getTriggerMetatDataByName(BindingDataStore.java:66)
[2023-01-24T03:35:12.083Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.ParameterResolver.resolve(ParameterResolver.java:62)
[2023-01-24T03:35:12.137Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.ParameterResolver.resolve(ParameterResolver.java:42)
[2023-01-24T03:35:12.139Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.execute(EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.java:53)
[2023-01-24T03:35:12.384Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:62)
[2023-01-24T03:35:12.387Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)
[2023-01-24T03:35:12.451Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
[2023-01-24T03:35:12.452Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)
[2023-01-24T03:35:12.453Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:92)      
[2023-01-24T03:35:12.472Z]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[2023-01-24T03:35:12.562Z]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[2023-01-24T03:35:12.569Z]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[2023-01-24T03:35:12.629Z]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[2023-01-24T03:35:12.963Z]      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I tried adding the name as a property in the delivery properties but that didn't work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue which is the same to me but didn't find the specific cause for that exception in my test cases.

Following the Same doc, Created Storage Account, Blob Triggered Java Azure Function with **ngrok Utility Endpoin**t given as a Web Hook Endpoint in Azure Event Subscription referenced to Blob Storage created earlier.

**Test Case 1**:

When I run the Function for the 1st time - uploaded a blob and overwritten the blob upload manually in the Blob Storage container. At that time, I got the `RuntimeException: Cannot find matched @BindingName` immediately after 1st Run with the Successful Trigger output:

[image]

[image]

**Test Case 2**:

During the same time of Function running with both the Blob Trigger File Upload Response and Runtime exception, I uploaded another blob file and got the expected result as Blob Trigger Response without any exception again and the Events also updated:

[image]

**Test Case 3**:

I have Stopped the Azure Function running locally in VS Code and Started again by uploading the new blobs in the Storage Container associated with it. Then, I did not get any runtime exceptions:

[image]

[image]

#### Updated Answer

> Thanks so much Hari Krishna. Before posting, I did the same. After I got the first error, I left the function running and still got the same error. I will try this again. Can you please let me know which versions you used in your pom file?

**pom.xml file code**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.function</groupId>
    <artifactId>BlobTriggerEventGrid</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Azure Java Functions</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.22.0</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
        <azure.functions.java.library.version>2.2.0</azure.functions.java.library.version>
        <functionAppName>BlobTriggerEventGrid</functionAppName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.functions.java.library.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- function app name -->
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                    <!-- function app resource group -->
                    <resourceGroup>java-functions-group</resourceGroup>
                    <!-- function app service plan name -->
                    <appServicePlanName>java-functions-app-service-plan</appServicePlanName>
                    <!-- function app region-->
                    <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details#supported-regions for all valid values -->
                    <region>westus</region>
                    <!-- function pricingTier, default to be consumption if not specified -->
                    <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details#supported-pricing-tiers for all valid values -->
                    <!-- <pricingTier></pricingTier> -->
                    <!-- Whether to disable application insights, default is false -->
                    <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details for all valid configurations for application insights-->
                    <!-- <disableAppInsights></disableAppInsights> -->
                    <runtime>
                        <!-- runtime os, could be windows, linux or docker-->
                        <os>windows</os>
                        <javaVersion>11</javaVersion>
                    </runtime>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>~4</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--Remove obj folder generated by .NET SDK in maven clean-->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>obj</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Hari Krishna. 

Before posting, I did the same. After I got the first error I left the function running and still got the same error. 

I will try this again. 

Can you please let me know which versions you used in your pom file?

Comment: Updated the answer with the pom file.